# How to deploy parent and selected modules in a multiple module projects using maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am working on a project which has many modules (>50) but only a few of them are intended to be deployed. I know there is the following flag property I can use:

```
<maven.deploy.skip>false</maven.deploy.skip>
```

1) But I have to put it to `false` into parent pom and `true` in every child pom which is not intended to deploy

2) If I put `true` into parent pom and `false` into the modules that I intended to deploy, it will miss the parent pom.

Is there any simpler way to deploy selected modules in a multiple modules project?

Comment: If the modules to deploy don't change over time the best solution should be the 1) you provided on your question because you need to deploy the **parent** pom

Answer (score 0):

if you configure the "maven.deploy.skip" property in you parent pom with the default value (true) all your sub modules get this default value. 
Only on the submodules that you want deploy you can change the property value with the false value. In this way you obtain your behaivor.

If you deploy the artifacts in a Jenkins Pipeline there are other features to skip deploy on some modules. What is your envirnoment of build and deploy?

Another way is to execute the single sumodule deploy manually with the maven command launched inside the submodule.